# How to access to web page using Groovy?

Tags: groovy

i try to connect to webpage using Groovy,

i tried this, it works when the URL is `www.google.fr`

```
String.metaClass.browse {
def handler = [(~/^Mac OS.*/)  : { "open $it".execute() }, (~/^Windows.*/) : { "cmd /C start $it".execute() },
(~/.*/)         : {
//--- assume Unix or Linux                        
def browsers = [ 'firefox'.'chrome' ]
//--- find a browser we know the location of
def browser = browsers.find {
"which $it".execute().waitFor() == 0
}
//--- and run it if one found
if( browser )
"$browser $it".execute()
}
]
def k = handler.find { k, v -> k.matcher( System.properties.'os.name' ).matches() }
k?.value( delegate )
}
www.google.fr".browse.()
```

if i put URL which download a file it throw Compilation error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does just using `String.metaClass.browse = { -> Desktop.desktop.browse(delegate) }` work in place of all the above code?

Comment: where should i put the url in your code?

Comment: Errrr.... what URL?  Just do that, and call `"http://www.google.com".browse()`

Comment: Sorry, the code should be: `String.metaClass.browse = { -> java.awt.Desktop.desktop.browse(new URI(delegate)) }`

Comment: i have this error: 
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.net.URI(java.lang.Class)

 at delegate$_run_closure1.doCall(delegate.groovy:1)

 at delegate.run(delegate.groovy:5) with your last code and i added  this "http://www.google.com".browse()

Comment: it works with this : java.awt.Desktop.desktop.browse "https://www.google.fr".toURI()

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add it as a method to the String class, you can do:

```
String.metaClass.browse = { -> 
    java.awt.Desktop.desktop.browse(new URI(delegate))
}
```

Then calling

```
"http://www.google.com".browse()
```

Will open your default browser